# Closing file descriptor in multithreaded program

Tags: c, multithreading, network-programming

I have a thread I made to accept incoming connections with:

```
pthread_t thread;

pthread_create(&thread, NULL, worker_func, NULL);
pthread_detach(thread);
```

Then `worker_func` does:

```
<snip>
fd = accept(GlobalFD, NULL, NULL);
<snip>
```

However, If I try to close `GlobalFD` in my original thread, accept will still block (I want it to fail if GlobalFD is closed).  I've looked online and at other questions and can't seem to find the answer to my particular problem.

Any ideas? 
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Different threads of the same program share memory, including file descriptor tables.  If one thread closes an FD then it is closed for all other threads, too.  This is one of the differences between using multiple threads and using multiple processes.  Therefore, do not allow one thread to close a file descriptor that another is relying upon to remain open.

More generally, however, you must take great care about modifying shared data.  Generally speaking, you must synchronize access via a semaphore, a condition variable, or some other construct or action with significance for synchronization.  Program behavior is otherwise not well defined.  In particular, you cannot expect that closing a file descriptor will cause an active I/O function running in a different thread to terminate.  Send the target thread a signal instead.

Comment: But when I close `GlobalFD` I WANT accept to fail, so that the thread will close gracefully! Edited in my main question.

Comment: It seems `pthread_kill(thread, SIGINT)` has no effect, with or without a signal handler.  It returns 0 however, which means it sent the signal..

Comment: I've just decided to connect to myself and send a string to terminate the thread.  I can't seem to get it to work otherwise.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @pika It's not a good idea to do that: When you open a new file, there is a high chance the file descriptor number is going to be reused.

Comment: @FUZxxl What do you mean?  I only connect to myself when I want to exit the program, and since I'm not using a GlobalFD anymore, I don't think there should be any conflict.

Comment: I can't explain why signaling isn't working.  Is there any chance that it *does* work, but the thread just loops back to perform a new `accept()`?  As for connecting to yourself and sending a termination message, I actually think that's pretty clean, *provided that* the server thread can distinguish such a message coming from the main thread from one coming from some random client.  Otherwise, it presents a vector for a DOS attack.

Answer (score 1):

In general, closing a file-descriptor in one thread isn't guaranteed to cause a function that's waiting on that file-descriptor in another thread to return.

Your options are 1) install a signal handler and use pthread_kill() (don't forget to check the return-code of the blocked function) and 2) create a "termination file-descriptor" that is also passed to the select() or poll() function and either close it or write to it in the other thread.

Good luck.